# Synchronization data between two SonarQube server

Tags: sonarqube

I deploy a system include two sonarqube webserver use the same database (MySQL 5.7).

Like the image below:

[image]

Two sonarqube server work well.

And, here is config for connect mysql:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://203.162.141.42:3306/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&useSSL=false
```

But I don't know why when I create a project in server sonarqube 1, the sonarqube 2 don't read information about this project.

This is project information in Sonar 1

[image]

This is project information in Sonar 2

[image]

Comment: Why do you think using 2 webservers using the same database on a database server instance is supported?

Comment: Because, when I add project in sonar server 1 (sonar server 2 stop service).Then, I stop service sonar in server 1 and start service sonar in server 2. I see in server 2 update one project, but the detail of project is not show.